# Install Ubuntu 12.04 on a formerly Win XP computer

Tags: installation

Any advice for a Novice? My laptop formerly had Win XP but no longer has XP. When I try to use USB to install Ubuntu 12.04, my laptop does not respond.

Comment: You may need to change you BIOS settings to boot from USB. If you laptop doesn't support this, then you can download the ISO and burn it to a disk.

Comment: Hard to tell from the info you gave. (1) How did you create the BOOTABLE USB? Simply copying the downloaded .iso file onto the USB will not work. (2) Did you manage to change your BIOS to boot from a USB? Another option is to create a bootable DVD and boot from that. (3) One thing you might want to do is to type the computer make and model and "ubuntu" into Google to see if a huge number of video problems show up. (4) Depending on the age of your laptop, you might want to consider a lighter distribution. (5) You might have to try a couple of times until you get an install you like.

Answer (score 0):

1.Insert Ubuntu Live USB and restart your computer, While restarting keep pressing ESC/F2/F9/F12 depending on your bios set up and select booting with USB.

2.In the booting option select try ubuntu. If you feel Ubuntu is working well then Click Install Ubuntu in the Harddrive.